# cpp 2D array changes on its own?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

In the following piece of code i create a 2D array, tab. Let `len_a=5,len_b=4` After the first `for` loop, `tab[0][5]` should be equal to 5, and it is. But, when i print the row, it changes value to 1. What's happening?

```
int len_a=a.length(),len_b=b.length();

    int tab[len_a+1][len_b+1];
    tab[0][0]=0;


    for(int i=1;i<=len_a;i++)//Init first row
        tab[0][i]=i;

    cout<<tab[0][5]<<endl;


    for(int j=1;j<=len_b;j++)//Init first column
        tab[j][0]=j;

    for(int i=0;i<=len_a;i++)//Print row
        cout<<tab[0][i]<<" | "<<i<<endl;

    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<=len_b;i++)
        cout<<tab[i][0]<<" | "<<i<<endl;
```

Outputs:

5 (first cout<< tab[0][5])

0 | 0

1 | 1

2 | 2

3 | 3

4 | 4

1 | 5 (second cout<< tab[0][5] ???)

0 | 0

1 | 1

2 | 2

3 | 3

4 | 4

Comment: C++ does not support variable length arrays.

Comment: Not able to reproduce exactly what you're asking about: https://ideone.com/ulWASA. Could we get a [mcve]?

Comment: If `len_a=5` and `len_b=4` your declaration (apart from being an illegal VLA) becomes `int tab[6][5];`. In C++ (and C), array indeces start from zero, so `tab[0][5]` is actually out of bounds, but, being arrays countiguos in memory, you are outputting element `tab[1][0]`.

Comment: You mix up A and B ; in the first loop you use `len_a` as loop condition but put the loop variable in the second (`b`) index

Answer (score 0):

C++ has 0 indexed arrays, which means that first element is 0 and last is N-1.

Example:

```
tab[2][3]; //creating array

tab[0][0]; //first element of array
tab[0][1];
tab[0][2]; //last element in the first row
tab[1][0];
tab[1][1];
tab[1][2]; //last element in the second row and last element in array
```

Any other element not mentioned above, like `tab[2][...]` or `tab[...][3]` is outside declared bounds array.

Since in example there was `tab[6][5]` created, `cout << tab[0][5];` is accessing something that is out of `tab` bounds. As @Bob__ mentioned arrays allocate continuous memory, so by accessing `tab[0][5]` in fact `tab[1][0]` is accessed. Second access to `tab[1][0]` element is after `//Init first column` occurred which overwrite value in `tab[1][0]` element.

BTW:
In the example there is first bracket swap with second. There should be:

```
int tab[len_a][len_b];

for(int i=0; i<=len_a; i++)//Init first row
    tab[i][0]=i; //not tab[0][i]
```